# Android Textview Selection not working

Tags: android, textview

I am using a TextView in my application. Here is the XML for that component.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_MyText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="90px"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>
```

Now in my code, I am setting movement method for my TextView using this code,

```
txt_MyText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

After setting the movement method, text view fails to make a selection of Text when user long presses the TextView. In Logs, I can see this message,

```
TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.
```

But if I remove the movement method code the TextView continues to allow selection.

What's going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the focus. The Android Doc has the explanation here:

void **setMovementMethod** (MovementMethod movement)

Sets the MovementMethod for handling arrow key movement for this TextView. This can be null to disallow using the arrow keys to move the cursor or scroll the view.

Be warned that if you want a **TextView** with a key listener or **movement method** not to be focusable, or if you want a TextView without a key listener or movement method to be focusable, **you must call setFocusable(boolean) again** after calling this to get the focusability back the way you want it.

**EDIT**

I believe it could be how you are setting your TextView's movementMethod.

Try it like so:

```
myTextView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: can you show some code of what is happening before & after the setMovementMethod?

Comment: I do not have any code before or after. I am dynamically appending text to the TextView as a user scroll down. Without ScrollingMovement method set the TextView resets to the initial position (Top, to the first line) after each append. But with that set, the text view remains at the same position where new text is inserted.

Comment: Okay let me start looking into this, ill get back to you in a sec if I can find anything. This seems like a strange issue here.

Comment: Okay, just to clarify. You are scrolling down and automatically adding text to the textview, correct? With the ScrollingMovement method set, this is stopping you from longpressing on the Textview?

Comment: Just for sanity sake, you have a txt_MyText.setOnLongClickListener() for that TextView?

Comment: Is the user trying to change the text after they are scrolling? or just to select it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147292/discussion-between-zach-and-a-petrizza).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
txt_MyText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
txt_MyText.setFocusable(true);
txt_MyText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: @Zach so why didn't you put this in your question as something you tried? Could've saved Rodrigo some time...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44679422/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: @Dev-iL Can I use that comment for reviewing? It's very good and useful.

Comment: How was i supposed to know if you have already tried to do this? Well, i make @Dev-iL ´s answer mine